retain data type of unstructured json attributes sent over go rpc
I'm encountering an issue with JSON marshaling and unmarshaling in Go. Specifically, I have an unstructured JSON object that includes attributes like "port", which is of type uint64. However, when marshaling this JSON using the encoding/json package, the uint64 values are being converted to float64.
This serialized JSON data is then sent over RPC (protobuf) as a []bytes type. However, when unmarshaling these []bytes back into a struct, I'm experiencing a loss in the original data type.
My question is whether there's a way to preserve the int and uint data types during both marshaling and unmarshaling processes to ensure data integrity throughout the communication flow.
example:
I have a map[string]interface{} data
map[config:map[port:80]] --> here port value 80 is of type uint64  

I can't directly send this map[string]interface{} over rpc message.
this map[string]interface{} has to be serialized ( marshalled ) first
into []bytes then sent over rpc.
by doing so uint64 data type of port will be converted to float64

JSON only supports number, string, array, object etc. types and so there's no way to differentiate between 1, +1 and 1.0. Because Go does disambiguate int, uint and float types, (un)marshaling JSON numbers should map to the correct field types and should error (!?) on e.g. 3.14 to int and -3 to uint.

See playground this behaves as I'd expect. You can play with the values of byte[] in line 37 to generate unmarshal errors when i (int) is a float or u (uint) is negative.

I'm confused by your question. You've tagged it protocol-buffers|grpc but you say that "serialized JSON data is then sent over RPC". This isn't the behavior when using protocol buffers. Protocol buffers uses its own (un)marshaling mechanism (not JSON).

updated question with example

I continue to be confused (my apologies!). I understand your type. So, a couple of things. First, if you want to represent arbitrary JSON using Protocol Buffers in Go, you can use Google's Well-known Types specifically Struct and Value. Second, you can't represent number types other than numbers in JSON; JSON isn't sufficiently descriptive to represent floats, uints etc.

Apologies, meant to include the link to the Go structpb module too as this provides a reasonable overview of how to incorporate it and to use JSON with Protobuf.
